# Javascript: Real time calculations in a form

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript I am working on a form that calculates in real time someone's BMI and TBW based on weight and height inputs. 
I am using a addEventListener and onkeyup. I am very new to JavaScript, so bear with me. 
What am I doing wrong?

Update: I have followed advice and replaced the "onkeyup" event with "oninput", and have put the height and weight values within the functions. I have also added .value. I am still have issues though.

```html
<body>
<form id="adime-form" name="adime" method="post">
<div class="three-column clear">
  <label for="">Age</label>
  <input type="number" name="age" id="age"> <!--Input-->
</div>
<div class="three-column">
  <label for="">Sex</label>
  <input type="text" name="sex" id="sex"><!--Input-->
</div>
<div class="three-column">
  <label for="">Height</label>
  <input type="number" name="height" id="height"><!--Input-->
</div>
<div class="three-column">
  <label for="">Weight</label>
  <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight"><!--Input-->
</div>
<div class="three-column">
  <label for="">BMI</label>
  <input type="text" name="bmi" id="bmi" oninput="returnBmi"><!--Output-->
</div>
<div class="three-column">
  <label for="">Total Body Water</label>
  <input type="text" name="tbw-perc" id="tbw-perc" oninput="returnTbw"><!--Output-->
</div>
</form>
 
<script>

var getAge = document.getElementById("age");
var getSex = document.getElementById("sex");

document.getElementById("bmi").addEventListener("input", returnBmi);
document.getElementById("tbw-perc").addEventListener("input", returnTbw);
 
function returnBmi(){
 var getHeight = document.getElementById("height").value;
 var getWeight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
 var getBmi = getWeight / (getHeight**2) * 703;
 document.getElementById("bmi").innerHTML = getBMI;
 
}
 
function returnTbw(){
 var getHeight = document.getElementById("height").value;
 var getWeight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
 var getTbw = -2.097 + 0.1069 *( getHeight * 2.54)  + 0.2466 * (getWeight * .45);
 document.getElementById("tbw-perc").innerHTML = getTbw;
 }


</script>
```

enter code here

Comment: `getHeight` and `getWeight` are DOM Objects.. you need to get `.value` of them

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the 'input' event on the inputs: `document.getElementById("bmi").addEventListener("input", returnBmi);`

Also, take the Weight and Height **values**, **INSIDE** the update function:

```
function returnBmi(){
  var getHeight = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var getWeight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
  var getBmi = getWeight / (getHeight**2) * 703;
  document.getElementById("bmi").innerHTML = getBMI;
}
```

As you need to extract the values when the event is triggered.

Comment: I added an "oninput" event to the inputs:

Comment: I updated my questions to show the changes I made to the code. I added all of your suggestions but am still having issues.